# loop in json and map key value python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a scenario where I am looping through a [json response](https://jsfiddle.net/4e8shbmz/) and trying to have a mapped key value pair.
objective : loop through the json file and search for values with name `content1` inside the `labels` object if found then return the corresponding value of `name`(TEST API1) and `id` (33332) and store it in a variable or list to further store it in csv file with format `name` and `id` and `content` name and adding a `sl num`.

Here is what I have tried already:

```
get_metadata = requests.get('https://testurl.com')
metadata = get_metadata.json()
for key in metadata:
    value = metadata[i]['labels']
    print('The key and value are ({}) = ({})'.format(key, value))
```

Here error occurs:

```
Error: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, 
not list`
```

How can I achieve the above objective what should be the approach any help would be great.
If anybody can help here how to proceed further in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
for dict_ in metadata:
    for label in dict_['labels']:
        if label['content'] == 'content1':
           print('The key and value are ({}) = ({})'.format(dict_['id'], 
dict_['name']))
```

The output:

```
The key and value are (33332) = (TEST API1)
```

If you want to export result as `CSV` file, try this:

```
import csv

with open('objects.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(
        csvfile, 
        delimiter=',',
        quotechar='|', 
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
    )
    for dict_ in metadata:
        for label in dict_['labels']:
            if label['content'] == 'content1':
                filewriter.writerow([dict_['id'], dict_['name']])
```

Comment: just wanted to understand if I wan to filter something like this `ABE content1` and I have another value as well which has `ABC content1` out of which I just only want to filter out values for `ABE content1` How do I do that ? because `content1` is a common term that is associated with both contents but I want to only filter out for `ABE content1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
>>> for key in metadata:
...     name = key['name']
...     label_info = key['labels']
...     for x in label_info:
...             print(f"{name}, {x['id']}, {x['content']}")
...
TEST API1, 667, content1
TEST API1, 668, content2
TEST API1, 669, content3
TEST API1, 112, content4
TEST API2, 668, content2
TEST API2, 669, content3
TEST API2, 112, content4
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need to check if there is content as `content1` in the json available if yes then only I need to print the `name`, `id ` and `content` value of that corresponding.
This code what you have given prints everything

Comment: then you just need an if statement in the inner for loop `if x['content'] == 'content1'`

Comment: Cool , thanks but how to I store this data in CSV file ?

Comment: Just wanted to understand if I wan to filter something like this `ABE content1` and I have another value as well which has `ABC content1` How do I do that ? beacause `content1` is a common term that is associated with both contents but I want to only filter out for `ABE content1`